# how to write an onclick function in joomla registration section

Tags: joomla2.5

First of all I am new to this joomla CMS. I have  a joomla project. here i have customized the userprofile plugin and added some more fields .
in registration form i need an extra button named "Save for later ". thus my form contains 3 button ( save for later, Register and cancel )

i need to write a javascript function in the onclick event of "save for later button ".

So i have done

In `components/com_user/views/registration/tpl/default.php` I have created a button as in normal way. and wrote a javascript function call on this

```
<input  type="submit" class="validate" value="Save For Later" name="SaveDraft" onclick="fnSaveDraft()">
```

At the top of the page i write the function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function fnSaveDraft() {
alert('hai');
return false;
}
</script>
```

But nothing happend

Please advise me

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to that don't change the core file unless you really needed.You can use the template overridden method for task.For detail go to that link.
[How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

And for your problem your are using the input type as `submit` that why your form will submitted and your function was not call. You can use type as button then your task will be done.Replace your input field with this.

```
<input  type="button" class="validate" value="Save For Later" name="SaveDraft" onclick="fnSaveDraft()">
```

Comment: Definitely user overrides, your changes will be wiped out the first time you update if you don't.